# Rails - newbie association question with both has_many and HABTM models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many, has-many

I have three models:

```
class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sites
end

class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tenant
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sites
end
```

For Site and Users, I have a join table (sites_users).

Every Site has n Users.  Every Tenant has n Sites.

To get a list of users for a specific site, it's easy:

```
t = Tenant.first
s = t.sites.first
s.users
```

But is there an association I can add to Tenant to provide a list of all users between all sites under that tenant?  So that I can do:

```
t = Tenant.first
t.users
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of people have asked for this, you'll see some discussion in the [Rails Lighthouse Ticket #8994](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/1152-support-for-nested-has_many-through-associations) of some developers trying to merge in the functionality of the [nested_has_many_through plugin](http://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through.git).  If you're on Rails 2.3, the [nested_has_many_through plugin](http://github.com/ianwhite/nested_has_many_through.git) might work for you, otherwise in Rails 3 you could write an [ARel](http://github.com/rails/arel) query to find the right set of studies.

Comment: Thanks, Patrick!  That Lighthouse ticket is encouraging.  I'll look into writing an ARel query for a stopgap solution.